# Scala console won't work, IntelliJ

Tags: scala, ide, console, intellij-idea

I did all the preference work, installed scala, everything works except this, i just can not test a scala class in the console window.

In tutorials I see they just type in something behind the scala> but it just won't work, i can type some random stuff there below which doesn't do anything when I press enter.

Can you guys help me out? I would be very thankful.
Cheers

Comment: Which versions of scala and IntelliJ do you use?

Comment: IntelliJ 12 community version (omg i love your name my gf says that all the time lol)

Comment: please tell us what platform you are on (MS Windows 7, OSX, Ubuntu?) and rather than "random stuff" type in some valid expression like val a="xyz"

Comment: its not working on mac osx 10.7 and on pc windows 7, i did valid expression val test = new Time bla bla bla doesn't do anything

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Once you type on the Scala console in IntelliJ Community Edition. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of enter to execute.

took me a while to get around it :)

> > > [IntelliJ & Working with Scala Worksheet](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Worksheet)

Comment: a hint somewhere or a tool tip would have been very helpful

Comment: Thanks kind stranger! IntelliJ, how is one supposed to know that. Wasted 30 mins trying to compute 5+5.

Comment: On OS X it is CMD+Enter.  Note that it is 2 years later and this awkwardness still persists.  I love JetBrains but really guys.

Comment: absolutely ridiculous and frustrating for first time users :(. Thank you very much.

Comment: Still frustrating for first time users in August 2019 (which is me, who is thankful for this answer), but I suppose it enables entering multiple lines before executing.

Answer (score 19):

If you want the console to execute when you hit enter, go to `Preferences > Keymap > Plug-ins > Scala`, and right-click `ScalaConsole.Execute`. Select `Add Bookmark` and hit enter in the first box. Then click `Apply` and then `OK`.
[image]

Comment: I've done this and checked that the keys are correct but it still won't run...any ideas?

Comment: For IDEA 2016.2, the sequence is now: File -> Settings... -> Keymap -> Plug-ins -> Scala. Double-click on "Execute Console Statement" and select "Add Keyboard Shortcut".  Now if I could figure out why the blinking cursor is 2 lines below the `scala>` prompt...

Comment: @jwvh did u find a fix? why its two lines below?

Answer (score 11):

You have to press ⌘-Enter on Mac OS X when you're done typing.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. My key shortcut is set correctly, but it does nothing. http://i.imgur.com/eOGRQbT.png

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's better to change the message from 
"Type in expressions to have them evaluated."
to 
"Type in expressions and press Ctrl + Enter to have them evaluated."

Answer (score 0):

Just add scala sources to $PATH and it should be available / callable from CMD / Idea Terminal