# error: not found: value isEven and error: not found: value isOdd

Tags: scala

I try to run an example from here: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.control.TailCalls$

```
scala> import scala.util.control.TailCalls._
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

scala> def isEven(xs: List[Int]): TailRec[Boolean] =
     |   if (xs.isEmpty) done(true) else tailcall(isOdd(xs.tail))
<console>:14: error: not found: value isOdd
         if (xs.isEmpty) done(true) else tailcall(isOdd(xs.tail))
                                                  ^

scala> 

scala> def isOdd(xs: List[Int]): TailRec[Boolean] =
     |  if (xs.isEmpty) done(false) else tailcall(isEven(xs.tail))
<console>:14: error: not found: value isEven
        if (xs.isEmpty) done(false) else tailcall(isEven(xs.tail))
                                                  ^

scala> 

scala> isEven((1 to 100000).toList).result
<console>:14: error: not found: value isEven
       isEven((1 to 100000).toList).result
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/32259574/1374461

Answer (score 3):

In REPL define the tail calls using `:paste` and finalize the editing with Control+D,

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.util.control.TailCalls._
def isEven(xs: List[Int]): TailRec[Boolean] =  if (xs.isEmpty) done(true) else tailcall(isOdd(xs.tail))
def isOdd(xs: List[Int]): TailRec[Boolean] =  if (xs.isEmpty) done(false) else tailcall(isEven(xs.tail))

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.util.control.TailCalls._
isEven: (xs: List[Int])util.control.TailCalls.TailRec[Boolean]
isOdd: (xs: List[Int])util.control.TailCalls.TailRec[Boolean]
```

This way REPL *waits* for all the definitions to be parsed at once, namely `isEven` and `isOdd` are parsed as `TailRec` mutual recursion.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are trying to use a function, which isn't defined yet. If you want to use REPL, you can wrap everything in an object or use "paste mode" as it is explained in another answer:

```
scala> object MyObject {
     |
     | def isEven(xs: List[Int]): TailRec[Boolean] =
     |   if (xs.isEmpty) done(true) else tailcall(isOdd(xs.tail))
     |
     | def isOdd(xs: List[Int]): TailRec[Boolean] =
     |  if (xs.isEmpty) done(false) else tailcall(isEven(xs.tail))
     |
     | isEven((1 to 100000).toList).result
     |
     | def fib(n: Int): TailRec[Int] =
     |   if (n < 2) done(n) else for {
     |     x <- tailcall(fib(n - 1))
     |     y <- tailcall(fib(n - 2))
     |   } yield (x + y)
     | }
defined object MyObject

scala> MyObject.fib(40).result
res5: Int = 102334155
```